# Where to find sound files for windows toast notifications?

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1, win-universal-app

I want to create an app where the user can select the sound for the toast notification sended by the app. I've found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/br230842.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) a link to MSDN where all possible sound types are described. But I want to play these files within my app and so I'm searching for the mp3/wav files on my harddrive, but I can't find them.
For example where I can find the audio file of 'ms-winsoundevent:Notification.SMS'?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On windows 8.1, go to c:\Windows\Media folder, you will find some .wav files like "Windows Notify Messaging.wav". See if that's what you want.